# How do I get custom document properties to export into PDF?

Tags: pdf, openoffice-writer

When I export a document to PDF, the Title, Author, and Subject export just fine. However the values in the "Custom Properties" tab in File | Properties, do not get exported into the PDF custom properties tab.

Is there any way to get these values to export into the PDF?

Comment: I'm looking to do similar (DOCX to PDF, keeping CustomDocumentProperties and Fields). Did you have any luck or solutions?

Comment: Scott_R Comment: Could you please indicate what operating system and can you confirm it is a PDF created by the OpenOffice software?